# why it says var count is local and referenced before assignment?

Tags: python

**This might not be the perfect sol for the problem i'm doing but all i want to know is why it says count is local and called before assignment.**

```
count = 0

def pal(num):
if (num[::-1] ==num):
    print(int(num))
    count+=1
    return (num[::-1])
else:
    return (num[::-1])

n = int(input())

while(count!=1):
    n += int(pal(str(n)))
```

the code works fine until the if statement is called in the function.

Comment: `count` is defined outside of `pal`, to access it add `global count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the global variable inside the method you need to use `global varname` inside the method. Details usage of `global` variable [can be read from the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value).

```
count = 0

def pal(num):
    global count
    if num[::-1] ==num:
        print(int(num))
        count+=1
        return num[::-1]
    else:
        return num[::-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input())
    while count!=1:
        n += int(pal(str(n)))
```

P.S. : I have removed few unnecessary parentheses.

**References:**

- [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

It is because count is a local variable. (I am guessing that is python.) In python, any code that changes the value of a variable makes that variable local to that function. In other words, it is seen as a separate variable from any global variable of the same name eg count in your code.
To fix this, add
`nonlocal count` or `global count` at the first line of your function that is in your case, immediately below `def pal(num):`. That will tell the python interpreter that count is actually not a local variable.

Comment: That was a proper explanation. Thanks !!.

Comment: Accept it then.

Answer (score 1):

you should set count as global from inside your function:

```
count = int(0)

def pal(num):
    global count
    if (num[::-1] ==num):
        print(int(num))
        count+=1
        return (num[::-1])
    else:
        return (num[::-1])

n = int(input())

while(count!=1):
    n += int(pal(str(n)))
```